# for intltelinput library not able to see the dropdown for countries in mobiles

Tags: javascript, jquery, aem

I recently updated to version 18 of the intl-tel-input library and am now experiencing issues with the mobile UI, specifically the country dropdown not being visible on mobile devices. This feature is working as expected in desktop mode when implemented through Adobe Experience Manager (AEM), but the problem arises in the mobile version. I've attempted solutions using both jQuery and vanilla JavaScript, but the issue persists. Could someone provide assistance or suggestions to resolve this problem?